# Trouble Dual Booting Ubuntu 14.04.5 and OS X

Tags: dual-boot, usb, mac, refind

I was following this guide:

http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/

on how to dual boot ubuntu 14.04.5 on my Macbook Pro (2012) and got stuck just after the Ubuntu installation. I'm using rEFInd to recognize the Ubuntu partition and a bootable USB to hold the Ubuntu image for installation, prepared following this guide:

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Ubuntu installs successfully, and after installing it says to restart the computer. However when I restart and select the Ubuntu partition (GRUB) and try to boot Ubuntu from there all I get is a black screen and Ubuntu never boots. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing kernel parameters from your grub config. What's your MBP model?

Comment: Wasn't sure what you were looking for so here's the hardware overview for my Macbook:



  Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro10,1
  Processor Name: Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 2.3 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory: 8 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP101.00EE.B0A
  SMC Version (system): 2.3f36
  Serial Number (system): C02HX34KDKQ1
  Hardware UUID: 967B66AF-E613-51C7-A120-EB009EAFA11F

Comment: I was looking for the MacBookPro10,1 part. I can't quite figure out why your setup wouldn't boot at this point. Have you tried passing 'nomodeset' to grub at boot? maybe its a video card driver issue? I usually install Ubuntu on my macs using refind as the bootloader and booting directly from the kernel stub instead of installing grub. There are a few guides out there on how to do this already. In case it helps, I'll try writing one up as an answer here as soon as I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

Before proceeding further, you should understand that EFI-mode booting is not about booting *partitions;* it's about booting *files.* This fact doesn't alter the mechanics of day-to-day booting, but it's critical for debugging boot problems and doing manual boot loader and boot manager installations. In BIOS, boot loaders reside in the Master Boot Record (MBR; that is, the first sector) of the hard disk and in the first sector (sometimes called the Partition Boot Record, or PBR) of partitions. Thus, it's sensible to talk about "booting a partition" or something similar, on a BIOS-based computer. Under EFI, though, boot loaders are stored in ordinary files on a FAT partition called the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) (On Macs, boot loaders can also reside on various HFS+ volumes.) Thus, "booting a partition" is pretty much meaningless under EFI. (One partial exception relates to the *fallback filename,* which is `EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` on AMD64 systems; this filename is booted if no other registered boot loader can be found. It's most often used on removable media to make them bootable.) If you think your EFI-based computer, such as a Mac, is "booting a partition," you're likely to go on a wild goose chase when trying to debug boot problems. That said, I don't think your problem is fundamentally about the boot process, although it could be there's a tie-in somewhere....

For your specific problem, I have three suggestions:

- Re-install rEFInd from OS X. Chances are your initial installation lacked an EFI filesystem driver for ext4fs (or whatever filesystem holds your Linux kernel). Re-installing now, after Ubuntu has been installed, should cause the `refind-install` script to set up the ext4fs driver, which will enable rEFInd to boot the Linux kernel directly. This may work better than going through GRUB. Note, however, that if you're using a filesystem other than ext4fs, you should instead install the appropriate filesystem driver manually. (See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html) of the rEFInd documentation for details.)
- See [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) for information on "black screen" problems. These problems were rampant about two years ago, but have become much less common today. Causes were varied, so you may need to try multiple solutions.
- Instead of installing the 2.5-year-old 14.04, install the 16.04.1 or 16.10 version of Ubuntu. These distributions include newer software and so may work around the problem you're encountering. (Of course, the 14.04.5 you're using includes updates to some critical components, such as the kernel; but it's still behind the times on other software, which might be the cause of your black-screen problem.)